How do i run a separate Selenium-IDE browser "SIDE" project from another "SIDE" project?
Goal: I am in a tiger team developing a solution to use Selenium-IDE, and want to run more complex processes via a script. This could be using Selenium-Side-Runner or directly using "execute async script". The goal is to make basic working tests now covering common scenarios, and later on worry about more complex programmatic solutions. We don't have access to a CD/CI pipeline yet in the truest sense, but I am also trying to build in a solution that could work for an eventual migration to the AWS cloud with those tools in mind.
Current Attempts: I started working with the selenium-side-runner and realize it executed so quickly that it was causing errors, long term building in pauses or waiting for components would add a great deal of work for the team. So, then I tried to use the execute script, but referencing a filesystem section seems unsupported.
Request: What methods do your teams use to run multiple side projects at the same time, and what concrete solutions would you recommend for my team? Do you have a solution for the selenium-side-runner executing to fast, and have you ever used the command "execute script" to run bash, or even python and what was that method?
Link1: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/385
Link2: Selenium IDE Test Runs in GUI - But Fails when run in CL (linkText not Visible)
Link1 is an old Github thread which shows it's a well requested problem that the team just gave up on i guess.
Link2 is from 3 years ago asking about a similar issue (that person just used pauses)
This is why I am also asking after other work arounds including running from a side project itself.
